# SQL display the total sales

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to select a total sales of each Category
Here is my table: (catNo = Category No. prodNo = product No.)

```
OrderLine:
prodNo ordNo actualPrice qty
P0001  OR001 3.00        20
P0002  OR002 3.00        2
P0003  OR003 500.00      25
Product:    
prodNo prodName  prodPrice   prodPhoto       stockQty catNo  suppNo
P0001  OverPower 1500.00     OP_C4_Black.jpg 10       CAT05  S0001
P0002  Vain      300.00      Vain.jpg        5        CAT04  S0002
P0003  test      500.00      test.jpg        40        CAT05 S0001
```

my SQL command is

```
SELECT `catNo` , sum(`actualPrice`*`qty`)as `Total Sales` 
FROM `orderline` , `product` 
WHERE `orderline`.`prodNo` = `product`.`prodNo` 
GROUP BY `orderline`.`prodNo`;
```

What I want is

```
catNo   Total Sales
CAT05   12560.00
CAT04   6.00
```

What actual output is

```
catNo   Total Sales
CAT05   60.00
CAT04   6.00
CAT05   12500.00
```

How can I display the total sales of each Category?

Comment: try `group by catNo` instead

Comment: Are you using mysql and sql server at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `catNo` , sum(`actualPrice`*`qty`)as `Total Sales` 
FROM `orderline` , `product` 
WHERE `orderline`.`prodNo` = `product`.`prodNo` 
GROUP BY `catNo`;
```

Try this, I hope it helps.

Comment: then you should accept and upvote the answer, so it can help to others :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of grouping by product number you should be grouping by category number:

```
SELECT `catNo` , sum(`actualPrice`*`qty`)as `Total Sales` 
FROM `orderline` , `product` 
WHERE `orderline`.`prodNo` = `product`.`prodNo` 
GROUP BY `Product`.`catNo`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by `catNo`. Then you will get the desired result:

```
SELECT `catNo` , sum(`actualPrice`*`qty`)as `Total Sales` 
FROM `orderline` , `product` 
WHERE `orderline`.`prodNo` = `product`.`prodNo` 
GROUP BY `catNo`
```

Result:

```
catNo   Total Sales
-------------------
CAT04   6
CAT05   12560
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f887/1)

Comment: @Adonis.C: Feel free to accept the answer (by selecting the tick mark on the left side of my answer) if you are satisfied. If you don't know how to accept an answer, please read [**this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).